# Break Selenium find_element_by_name into phases

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium on Python 3 with find_element_by_name on a website with a scrolling feed. This feed is updated in some kind of ajax format. This is running too fast for the ajax to load and leading to a stale element error.

Here the part of my script I'm interested in:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"foo")]'):
    print(element.text)
```

I've tried running this sequence in a try except block with implicit waits but it looks like driver.find_elements_by_xpath scrolls in its entirety before any except block could catch it.

Here is what I tried:

```
i = 0

def gatherElements():
    for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"foo")]'):
        print(element.text)
            i+=1

while i < 8000:
    try:
        gatherElements()
    
    except:
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        gatherElements()

    driver.implicitly_wait(12)
```

This is why I'm looking to break find_elements_by_xpath into manageable chunks. I would run x elements through, wait, then run another x elements through until completed.

Comment: It's probably me, but when you say `it looks like driver.find_elements_by_xpath scrolls in its entirety before any except block could catch it.` -- I'm not sure what you mean by "scrolls in its entirety"?

Comment: No problem. I wasn't expecting it to, but when I run find_elements_by_xpath it actually scrolls the feed and brings the next element up. The feed only shows 10 elements at a time before needing to reload. This script very quickly runs through those 10. I would like to be able to find those first 10, wait for the next few to load, gather the new ones, and repeat until finished. With the current process trying to load every element (including the ajax calls) before running the next line of code, the except block can't catch anything and the whole program fails early.

Comment: If i understood correctly, the next batch of elements appear after you scroll down the page ? If so, there is a way to scroll down, to load all elements, that are loaded using the "lazy load", untill there are none. Then you can wait for 15 seconds and retrieve all at once. It might be a cleaner method.

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to do 10 elements, then pause, then 10 more etc... I would try this:

```
import time

for i in range(8000):
    i += 1   
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"foo")]:nth-of-type(' + i + ')')
    print(element.text)
        if i % 10 == 0:
            time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have thought to use nth-of-type. Unfortunately, this came back with a type error: ````Cannot concatenate str (not int) to str```` Do you know of any good docs for leveraging CSS selectors with Selenium?

Comment: I've tried including a str( i ) conversion but it's now com back with ````'//span[contains(text(),"@")]:nth-of-type(1)') is not a valid xpath expression````.